# Supress expansion of * in echo

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, echo

I am working on a script which dynamically executes some queries on daily basis. These queries are coming from a table in the database.

Here is the sample output of the query table:

```
+---------------+-------------------------------+---------+
| query_name    | query                         | userid  |
+---------------+-------------------------------+---------+
| All_User      | select * from users LIMIT 10; | jmatthe |
+---------------+-------------------------------+---------+
```

Now, I have to execute the query `select * from users LIMIT 10;` dynamically. I am reading each line of the output and storing the query from the output.

```
query_name=$(echo $query | cut -d\| -f1)
query_sql=$(echo $query | cut -d\| -f2)
query_user=$(echo $query | cut -d\| -f3)
```

Now here is where the problem arises. Because my line contains a `*` character in it, `echo $query` expands the `*` to replace it with the files in the current directory. So basically, my `query_sql` stores something like this.

```
select batchemail.sh query_output.txt from tbl_query
```

I want to preserve the `*` in the line so that I get the same in my `query_sql` variable. I want my `query_sql` variable to store the original data.

```
select * from tbl_query
```

Can anybody guide me on this?

Comment: In zsh: `noglob echo *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set -f to disable globbing:

```
$ q='select * from users LIMIT '
$ set -f
$ echo $q
select * from users LIMIT
```

Comment: Thanks. Too bad. I thought escaping the * would help me, but now the query doesn't work.

Comment: I have a strange feeling... How do you run the query?

Answer (score 11):

Use double quotes around the variable:

```
query_name=$(echo "$query" | cut -d\| -f1)
query_sql=$(echo "$query" | cut -d\| -f2)
query_user=$(echo "$query" | cut -d\| -f3)
```